# Setting up additional monitors Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a problem with setting up additional (Acer)monitors.

In windows i have a 3 monitor setup using an HDMI, DP and docking station.

I have ubuntu 16.04 as a dual boot system and my HDMI monitor works perfectly fine. However as soon as I connect another screen to my laptop using the DP the additional screen says "no signal", my laptop lags and i can't even get the display settings to start up.

My laptop is perfectly capable of handling 3 monitors as i have the Acer Predator 15 with the Nvidia 980m GTX graphics card.

I have tried just unplugging everything, downloaded the new graphics software, updated/installed the kernel version 4.

I really need more than one screen to work from.

I am at a loss for solutions. And to be honest i am scared to edit boot settings and so on. Unless its the only way to solve the problem i will do it. 
I am not the best with Linux and Ubuntu, but i would however appreciate the help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you use a tool like arandr, is the screen shown as an available device?

Comment: are you using nouveau drivers or nvidia (you should use nvidia, nouveau can't really handle multiple screens)

Comment: No it doesn't show. It only shows the hdmi extra :-( The monitor comes on but then indicates no signal and my mouse lags

Comment: I am using the NVIDIA drivers, the latest version i have is 370.28  Fl.pf